# HTML5 Canvas - Calculate speed of object in relation to a 'magnet'

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

I have a 'magnet' directly in the middle of my Canvas and I have objects which are added to the Canvas on click. They're then attracted to the magnet.

I have X and Y distances of the objects in relation to each other, ranging between roughly -20 and 20.

This is the calculation I am using for the objects to attract, which works but the closer it gets, the weaker the force, when it should be the other way around, how can I do this?

```
impulseX = (distanceX / 100)
impulseY = (distanceY / 100)
```

Examples:

```
Distance = 20, speed = 0.05
Distance = 10, speed = 0.1
Distance = -20, speed = -0.05
Distance = -10, speed = -0.1
```

Example of what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/qk8Wk/

Thanks

Comment: Can you prepare a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please?!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qk8Wk/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation <=

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your impulse should follow the *inverse square law*, i.e.

```
var distance2 = distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY;
var mag = n / distance2;
```

where `n` is a general constant representing the strength of the field.

Then the impulse needs to be in proportion to the *direction* of that impulse:

```
var theta = Math.atan2(distanceY, distanceX);
var impulseX = mag * Math.cos(theta);
var impulseY = mag * Math.sin(theta);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/BH5qL/

or, avoiding the trig functions (per @JayC)

```
var norm = Math.sqrt(distance2);
var impulseX = mag * (distanceX / norm);
var impulseY = mag * (distanceY / norm);
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, the use of the math trigonometric functions isn't necessary.  If you let some value `norm=Math.sqrt(distanceX * distanceX + distanceY * distanceY)`, then `cos(theta)` is mathematically equivalent to `distanceX/norm` and similarly `distanceY/norm` for `sin(theta)`.  Note I said, "mathematically" equivalent, as in with floating points you may get different results.  But, as the value is passing through less operations, I'd expect the quality of the values to be better if you avoid the trig functions altogether.

Comment: @JayC good point, although using trig is probably easier to follow (initially).

Comment: Great solution, this works great. I definitely wasn't even thinking along the right track to come up with what I wanted.

Comment: Found a glitch, in fiddle, quite funny :D, hold mouse in the middle of the big white sphere.

Answer (score 1):

how about:

```
var distance = Math.sqrt(distanceX*distanceX + distanceY*distanceY)
impulseX = 0.1*distanceX / distance
impulseY = 0.1*distanceY / distance
```

or you can use the distance^2:

```
var distance2 = distanceX*distanceX + distanceY*distanceY
impulseX = 0.1*distanceX / distance2
impulseY = 0.1*distanceY / distance2
```

Comment: you haven't taken the _direction_ of the impulse into account

Comment: you are right, I figured its a vector and added `X` suffix at the last moment. Now fixed.

Comment: Hi I accepted another answer but this solution also works great and has a slightly different affect :) Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

> but the closer it gets, the weaker the force,

Quite logical, because the difference gets smaller – so difference / 100 gets smaller, too.

> when it should be the other way around, how can I do this?

Make the value you base your factor multiplication on get larger, not smaller – f.e.

```
impulseX = ( (20 - distanceX) / 100)
```